# Browser quit automatically by using selenium on chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The simple code like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.baidu.com')
```

It runs well , but! The opened browser quit automatically.
Some infos below

1. i have more selenium develop experience , this issue i met it these days on teaching my students.
2. chromedriver version : 107.0.5304.62
3. chrome version : 107.0.5304.107
4. selenium version : 4.6
5. python version : 3.10

It can work fine on an other PC1. I can't find the difference between them.
I try to collect the selenium log .

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service_args=['--verbose'],service_log_path='selenium.log')
    driver.get('https://www.baidu.com')
```

I get the log on PC1 too.
I found the difference , but i can't sure it is the source of this issue , also i can't solve it.

Here is the doubtful point:
`[1669339280.964][INFO]: [9a850cc416a680214e963aab4064f86b] COMMAND QuitAll { } [1669339281.111][INFO]: [9a850cc416a680214e963aab4064f86b] RESPONSE QuitAll` 
That's all , please give me some advices. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Options`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(<chromedriver.exe path>), options=options)
```

Comment: Thank u . But i dont agree ur idea . The same code runs well on the other PC, it won't quit automatically, how to explain this , i write the same code for a long time . It always works fine, only 2% students' enviroment have this issue.

Comment: I also search and got ur code on the web, but i didn't agree this.

Comment: I was also facing this issue You can refer  https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities - check 'detach'. If you don't agree that too, sorry, best of luck.

Comment: Thank u bro. I downgrade my selenium version 4.6-> 4.3 .  It works well.